# not able to use rJava after installing the package successfully

Tags: r, rjava

I am not able to use rJava after installing the package successfully.

> library("rJava") Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:   call: dirname(this$RuntimeLib)   error: a character vector argument expected Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’

Comment: Don't you think a few more details might be needed????

Comment: have you installed java, not the r package, but the runtime environment for the Java language?